# Return json object from dojo.xhrget

Tags: json, dojo

I am trying to get the json object from a dojo xhrGet call.

What I want is jsonobject = stuff;

I can see the json object in the console, but cannot access it!

```
   var xhrargs = {
    url: "/rest/url",
    handleAs: "json",
    preventCache : false,
    load: function(json_results){
      console.log(json_results);
      store = json_results;
      return dojo.toJson.json_results;
    },
    error: function(response, ioArgs) {
      console.error(response);
      console.error(response.stack);
    }   
   };

    var deferred = dojo.xhrGet(xhrargs);
    console.log("Json is "+JSON.stringify(deferred));
```

The console.log part that shows the json_results is fine, exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3):

The `dojo.xhrXXX` methods are asynchronous.  This means that the lines following

```
var deferred = dojo.xhrGet(xhrargs);
```

Will continue to execute while the call to an external endpoint is processing.  This means you need to use the promise API to tell a certain block of code to execute once the XHR request is complete:

```
var deferred = dojo.xhrGet(xhrargs);
deferred.then(function(result){
    //this function executes when the deferred is resolved (complete)
    console.log('result of xhr is ',result);
});
```

Due to the asynchronous nature of the request, for most intents and purposes that value doesn't exist outside the scope of the callback function.  One way to structure your code around this is in multiple blocks. for example:

```
var xhrLoaded = function(results){
    console.log('results = ',results);
    store = results;
}

var  performXhr = function(){
    var xhrargs = {
        url: "/rest/url",
        handleAs: "json",
        preventCache : false,
        error: function(response, ioArgs) {
          console.error(response);
          console.error(response.stack);
        }   
    };
    var deferred = dojo.xhrGet(xhrargs);
    deferred.then(xhrLoaded);
}

performXhr();
```

You can still access variables outside of the scope of the function (for example if `store` were defined globally).

Comment: Thanks! I'm really new to javascript and this is something I'm obviously not getting. Is it possible to get the json data from outside? Doing deferred.then .... gets me the json data as well, but I still can't get it from outside the function so I'm no better off than I was before.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    var xhrArgs = {
              url:"MethodName.action?Id="+id,
              handleAs: "json",
              load: function(Data){               
                var values = Data;  
                var count = Object.keys(values).length // gives u all keys count in a json object. In mine it is 0,1,2,3

                for (var i =0; i<count; i++){
                    var temp = values[i]; // values['name']
                  // do somthing ..
                    }
                }                   
              },
              error: function(error){       
                      alert(error);
              }                   
    }
    dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
```